# JDBC issues SET NAMES utf8 causes Illegal mix of collations

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

Today, one of java engineer come to me, and show me an error:

```
select * from some_table where name=? ...
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

The default charset is utf8 and collate is utf8_general_ci, the charset for column name is utf8mb4 and collate is utf8mb4_unicode_ci and the value for column 'name' is a utf8mb4 value(including emoji).

So i checked the database configuration and found :

```
character_set_client=utf8
character_set_connection=utf8
character_set_server=utf8
```

So, i think it's easy to fix this error:

```
set global character_set_server=utf8mb4;
set global collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
set global init_connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

But after restart the java program, the error still there!
So i enabled the general log in the MySQL server, and found very strange SQL statement:

```
4584243 Connect some_user@10.17.1.100 on some_database
4584243 Query   SET NAMES utf8mb4     # this is the result for the init_connect.
Query   /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.35 ( Revision: 
5fb9c5849535c13917c2cf9baaece6ef9693ef27 ) */SHOW VARIABLES WHERE 
Variable_name ='language' OR Variable_name = 'net_write_timeout' OR 
Variable_name = 'interactive_timeout' OR Variable_name = 'wait_timeout' OR 
Variable_name = 'character_set_client' OR Variable_name = 
'character_set_connection' OR Variable_name = 'character_set' OR 
Variable_name = 'character_set_server' OR Variable_name = 'tx_isolation' OR 
Variable_name = 'transaction_isolation' OR Variable_name = 
'character_set_results' OR Variable_name = 'timezone' OR Variable_name = 
'time_zone' OR Variable_name = 'system_time_zone' OR Variable_name = 
'lower_case_table_names' OR Variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet' OR 
Variable_name = 'net_buffer_length' OR Variable_name = 'sql_mode' OR 
Variable_name = 'query_cache_type' OR Variable_name = 'query_cache_size' OR 
Variable_name = 'license' OR Variable_name = 'init_connect'
4584243 Query   /* mysql-connector-java-5.1.35 ( Revision: 
5fb9c5849535c13917c2cf9baaece6ef9693ef27 ) */SELECT 
 @@session.auto_increment_increment
4584243 Query   SELECT @@session.autocommit
4584243 Query   SET NAMES utf8       # Who issued this?
4584243 Query   SET character_set_results = NULL
4584243 Query   SET autocommit=1
4584243 Query   select @@session.tx_read_only
4584243 Query   SELECT @@session.tx_isolation
4584243 Query   select  *  from  some_table where name = 'xxxx'  # OK, now normal business SQL statement starts
```

It can clearly seen that there is a SQL:

```
4584243 Query   SET NAMES utf8       # JDBC issued this
```

This SQL causes my fix to lose effect. Who or what framework will issue this kind of SQL, how to disabled it?

Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Updated:
I think it's not JDBC but MySQL server caused this problem, as when i use native JDBC connect to another server with init_connect='set names utf8mb4', the client connection's charset is set to utf8mb4 correctly, I have no idea why it's not work for this MySQL server. Both servers have the same configuration for charset and collation.

Updated：
After I restart MySQL server, the problem is gone! There maybe a bug in Connector J or MySQL server, as the document says the character_set_server and collation-server are dynamic options but in fact it's not true for all of the clients: it works for native mysql client but not for Connector J.

Comment: There is also the connection string in mysql where "utf8" is normally set.

Answer (score 1):

Updated：
The character_set_server option is not dynamic as the document says, but you can work around by adding connectionCollation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci to jdbc config string or just restart your MySQL server which maybe not acceptable in all cases.